# PERL file runs only on apache restart on xampp

Tags: perl, apache, xampp

I am running my perl file on XAMPP. First time I execute it then it works OK, but when I refresh it then it doesn't run. To make it run, I have to restart apachee. Can anybody please let me know the reason and solution?

PERL CODE IS: code

```
#!"D:\xampp\perl" 
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n"; 
print "<H1>Hello World</H1>\n"; 
require 'D:\xampp\htdocs\sa\settings.pl';
```

Comment: What is the perl code in question? What does your error_log say?

Comment: PERL CODE IS: `code` #!"D:\xampp\perl"


print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
print "<H1>Hello World</H1>\n";
require 'D:\xampp\htdocs\sa\settings.pl';

Comment: When I remove "require <path>" Then it works fine. After adding require I am facing this behaviour.

Comment: @Bhushan You can edit your own question to show things like that code.

Comment: I have resolved issue by replacing 'require' with 'do'. Is it proper way in perl. Please confirm.

Comment: No, I would not consider this "proper". The correct way to do it depends on what `settings.pl` is supposed to do with each run of the CGI program.

Answer (score 1):

```
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n"
```

Why aren't you using the CGI module with it's header method?

> When I remove "require " Then it works fine

Then your error_log file should tell you what is going wrong. You don't check for the files existence before requiring it. You should also be including:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
```

and test running the file from the command line. You should read up on debugging Perl and CGI programs.